# ajax call-if the user is login

Tags: ajax

Eu Comecei um novo aplicativo em HTML5 e Ele Recupera os dados da database por ajax
Comecei com este código: é um sistema online de pontuação e eu gostava de mudá-lo para recuperar o user_points coluna.
Por exemplo, se o usuário está login eu quero recuperar os seus pontos.
Este código chama todos os pontos dos usuarios 
eu gostava de mudar para recuperar apenas os dados do usuário que está logado.

A database é Composta Por database publiadd_loginsx table users columns user_email user_id user_name user_pass user_points

```html
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');




$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="user"; // Mysql username 
$password="pass"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="database"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_points DESC LIMIT 10";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Start looping rows in mysql database.
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $rows['user_name'] . "|" . $rows['user_points'] . "|";

// close while loop 
}

// close MySQL connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em **Português**. Por favor, traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu Comecei um novo aplicativo em HTML5 e quero chamar os dados da base de dados correspondentes ao usuario logado neste caso user_points bom este codigo ele faz isso mas tras me todos os usuarios disponiveis nessa coluna e eu queria chamar so o do usuario logado o que tenho de alterar para que possa so chamar os user_points so desse usuario?

Comment: helder, traduza o texto da sua pergunta clicando em [edit], para que ela não seja fechada por estar em outro idioma.